# How to get rid of Cached Location in Android

Tags: android, caching, gps, location, android-location

As you can see in the location strategies page of Google at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html that location once read is stored in cache (for quick reference picture attached)[image]

As you can see location is Cached and dismissed as it gets too old. I don't wanna use this cache. How can i disable it so that Each time Google Listen and retrieve Fresh location (I don't care about batteries just care about more accurate location)